# CFG and closure properties

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages

I am solving one problem and I urgently need a hint to solve one problem:

> Use closure under union to show that the following language is context-free:
>
> {a<sup>m</sup> b<sup>n</sup> c<sup>p</sup> d<sup>q</sup> : n=q or m <= p or m+n=p+q }

Comment: Since this isn't programming-related, I would suggest asking it at cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven’t specified what your problem is I will just go through what you need to know.

**Closed under union** - what does it mean? 
If we have a language `L` and a language `S` and both are context-free we know that the union of the languages is also context free.

> L ∪ S = A Context-free Language

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Closure_properties) for more closure properties of CFLs and you can find proofs of this on the web if you are interested (or you can try to make your own proof).

**How can you use this to solve your problem?** 
You have this language specification (let’s call it `L`):

> L = {a<sup>m</sup> b<sup>n</sup> c<sup>p</sup> d<sup>q</sup> : n=q or m <= p or m+n=p+q }

You can split this language into 3 other languages:

> A = {a<sup>m</sup> b<sup>n</sup> c<sup>p</sup> d<sup>q</sup> : n = q } 
> B = {a<sup>m</sup> b<sup>n</sup> c<sup>p</sup> d<sup>q</sup> : m <= p }
> C = {a<sup>m</sup> b<sup>n</sup> c<sup>p</sup> d<sup>q</sup> : m+n = p+q }

It is easy to see that `A ∪ B ∪ C = L`.

If you can prove that A, B and C are context-free you can conclude that L is also context-free.

**Solution**
To determine whether a language is context-free, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3510165/1401257). To quote the answer:

> First, you should attempt to build a [context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) that forms the language in subject. A grammar is context-free if left-hand sides of all productions contain exactly one non-terminal symbol. By definition, if one exists, then the language is context-free.
>
> An equivalent construct would be a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton). It's the same as DFA, but with a stack available. It may be easier to build than a grammar.

So if you can build a CFG (or a PDA) for each of the languages A, B and C, you have solved your problem.

Let’s take language `A`:
We need a grammar that generates a string of the form `a..b..c..d..` where we must have an equal amount of `b`s and `d`s.

```
S -> AE
A -> Aa  | ε
E -> bEd | C
C -> Cc  | ε
```

`S` is the start variable (or non-terminal), `ε` is the empty string (some people use null symbol `^` but I have always been told to use `ε`). This grammar should be able to generate the language `A` and therefore `A` is a context-free. (Please let me know if anyone detects an error. I haven't created CFGs in a while).

Since this is an exercise I will let you solve the remaining parts, but you should have gotten an idea of how to do it.

Comment: huge thanks for such a great text!